# Having a second helper call inside a helper, overwrites the first helper value in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

If I have helpers like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("testHelper", function (v) {
  console.log(v);
}
Handlebars.registerHelper("testHelper2", function (v) {
  return v;
}
```

and have two subhelpers like:

```
{{testHelper first=(testHelper2 '1') second=(testHelper2 '2')}}
```

both first and second are returning '2'.  The console output is:

```
data: {},
hash: {
   first: '2',
   second: '2'
}
```

How would I make it return the correct values?  If I do the following it returns first as 1:

```
{{testHelper first=(testHelper2 '1')}}
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this?  Please note that I made the helpers simple and wouldn't use a helper to return the same value normally.

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BdsTu/4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I see is to not use a hash as parameter for first helper. Instead of it use arguments directly.

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("testHelper", function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return 'first: '+args[0]+' second: '+args[1];
});
```

Template:

```
{{testHelper (testHelper2 '1') (testHelper2 '2')}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udL4J/).